# What class of algorithms can be used to solve this?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

**EDIT: Just to make sure someone is not breaking their head on the problem... I am not looking for the best optimal algorithm. Some heuristic that makes sense is fine.**

I made a previous attempt at formulating this and realized I did not do a great job at it so I removed that question. I have taken another shot at formulating my problem. Please feel free to provide any constructive criticism that can help me improve this.

**Input:**

- N people
- k announcements that I can make
- Distance that my voice can be heard (say 5 meters) i.e. I may decide to announce or not depending on the number of people within these 5 meters

**Goal:**

- Maximize the total number of people who have heard my k announcements and (optionally) minimize the time in which I can finish announcing all k announcements

**Constraints:**

- Once a person hears my announcement, he is be removed from the total i.e. if he had heard my first announcement, I do not count him even if he hears my second announcement
- I can see the same person as well as the same set of people within my proximity

**Example:**
Let us consider 10 people numbered from 1 to 10 and the following pattern of arrival:

- Time slot 1: 1 (payoff = 1)
- Time slot 2: 2 3 4 5 (payoff = 4)
- Time slot 3: 5 6 7 8 (payoff = 4 if no announcement was made previously in time slot 2, 3 if an announcement was made in time slot 2)
- Time slot 4: 9 10 (payoff = 2)

and I am given 2 announcements to make. Now if I were an oracle, I would choose time slots 2 and time slots 3 because then 7 people would have heard (because 5 already heard my announcement in Time slot 2, I do not consider him anymore). I am looking for an online algorithm that will help me make these decisions on whether or not to make an announcement and if so based on what factors. Does anyone have any ideas on what algorithms can be used to solve this or a simpler version of this problem?

Comment: Interesting Problem. I think any heuristic approach is going to rely on either knowing, estimating, or assuming a probability for a person joining or leaving during any timeslot. Do you have any information on this? For example, if you knew for a fact that everyone would leave after one timeslot, you would announce differently than if you knew most people tended to linger for several time slots.

Comment: @bdk: Actually you bring up an important point. I think when someone enters my proximity, I can probably estimate how many timeslots they can stay in my proximity. But I am interested in both approaches but something can be done only based on this assumption, that would be fine as well.

Comment: I think this looks promising as far as a general class of problems: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_decision_process. It seems to take into account the value gained by announcing at a specific state (timeslot) as well as a way to discount potential gains in the future that may or may not occur based on holding back an announcement. I'm posting as a comment and not an answer since this doesn't really help you too much without a mapping from your problem to a value function that takes the limited announcements into account, but I thought it might be valuable to throw it out there

Comment: @bdk: +1 Appreciate your time on this. I will start reading up on that and see if I can reduce my problem to be able to utilize the concept. I have not much experience with this so I will first start looking for simpler examples to understand it.

Comment: can you share the real world application you want to apply this to, or hint at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that there is really a way to solve this or an algorithm to do it the way you have formulated it.

It seems like basically you are trying to reach the maximum number of people with exactly 2 announcements.  But without knowing any information about the groups of people in advance, you can't really make any kind of intelligent decision about whether or not to use your first announcement.  Your second one at least has the benefit of knowing when not to be used (i.e. if the group has no new members then you can know its not worth wasting the announcement).  But it still has basically the same problem.

The only real way to solve this is to use knowledge about the type of data or the desired outcome to make guesses.  If you know that groups average 100 people with a standard deviation of 10, then you could just refuse to announce if less than 90 people are present.  Or, if you know you need to reach at least 100 people with two announcements, you could choose never to announce to less than 50 at once.  Obviously those approaches risk never announcing at all if the actual data does not meet what you would expect.  But that's always going to be a risk, since you could get 1 person in the first group and then 0 in all of the rest, no matter what you do.

Or, you could try more clearly defining the problem, I have a hard time figuring out how to relate this to computers.

Comment: +1 Thank You. From what you suggested, perhaps it would be good if I had an estimate of how popular my location is i.e. if my location is not popular at all, then it makes sense for me to choose a lower number to announce to reduce my risk of not getting anymore people but on the other side, if I am at a hotspot, I can probably take my chances of waiting for a lot more people. Now defining all the ambiguous terms in my comment will be tricky though :) And as I mentioned in my question, I am actually formulating the problem itself so I am open to tweaking it to make it solvable.

Answer (score 2):

There should be an approach relying upon a max-flow algorithm. In essence, you're trying to push the maximum amount of messages from start->end. Though it would be multidimensional, you could have a super-sink, which connects to each value of t, then have each value of t connect to the people you can reach at this time and then have a super-sink. This way, you simply have to compute a max-flow (with the added constraint of no more than k shouts, which should be solvable with a bit of dynamic programming). It's a terrifically dirty way to solve it, but it should get the job done deterministically and without the use of heuristics.

Comment: @Ben Stott: Hmm... may be I don't fully understand this but doesn't max-flow assume that we already have a graph? In my case, the decision is online and probably I need to construct each level of the graph... Ahh... I may be mistaken. Would you mind relating this to my problem or probably giving a small example?

Comment: What do you mean by 'online'? As in you only get data as and when it comes to you and you're already expected to have made a decision before then, or something else?
Specifically, is it *critical* that your algorithm solves the question for each value of t, or can you wait until all input is taken and work from there?

Comment: @Ben Stott: Oh so I am using online to mean that I need to take an immediate decision at t or I will never be able to take it again i.e. if I see 30 people and I miss the opportunity, I may never see them again so I need to decide on what to do at that point.

Comment: Yes, that's what the above algorithm will do. As long as you're able to wait until you've received all input before calculating anything, the above algorithm should work.
Specifically, for each t, add the node t to your first layer of nodes, as a child of the super-source. Then add each person that time t lets you speak to to your second layer, as a child of t and as a parent of the super-sink. Then, at the end of your input list, you can run a basic max-flow to answer your question. It will still take into account seeing 30 people at once!

Comment: @Ben Stott: Ok... Consider me a dunce. I just want to make sure that the way I am explaining myself and the way you are understanding me are the same. May be I am good with learning through an example. Can you show me how to do this on the toy example I provided in my question? I am just afraid that we both mean different things when we are saying input. In my opinion, input is the input at that time slot.. and I can never go back in time nor forward and I need to decide whether I will use my announcement then or not.

Comment: Okay, I'll use an edge-list for typing simplicity, but you should be able to use any form of node to make this work:
Sink: t1, t2, t3, t4
t1: p1
t2: p2, p3, p4, p5
t3: p5, p6, p7, p8
t4: p9, p10
p1...10: super-sink.
Every edge has a weight of 1. Using a bfs-style max flow, you'd force flow down k of the edges close to the sink. Let's use a naive brute-force here, but using an array to store common edges will make this O(n).
Forcing flow down t1: flow of 1.
Forcing flow down t2: flow of 4.
Forcing flow down t3: flow of 3. (used p5)
Forcing flow down t4: flow of 2.
Pick the highest 2: flow of 7.

Comment: @Ben Stott- I'm pretty sure your requirement that he's "able to wait until you've received all input before calculating anything" for a maxflow approach to work doesn't hold in Legend's problem, which is what he means by "online algorithm", eg. he needs to make a go / no go decision at each timeslot without waiting to see what happens in future timeslots.

Comment: @bdk: I second that. I can not wait until I see all my inputs. I think this class of problems fall into optimal stopping or online algorithms. I may be completely off track though as I am not an expert. But +1 to Ben Stott anyways :) Thank you for your time.

Comment: That's not quite the way I've interpreted it, but if that were the case one would be stuck using a Markov chain. No heuristic would be able to determine whether or not you could take this position, because there's no way to determine whether or not a second ahead has a billion people. If anything, I'd think any deterministic algorithmic approach here would be left clutching at straws....

Comment: Ah, well, if this is the case, you're stuck on a Markov process or some similar form of decision process that will offset potential gains against potential problems. Sorry I couldn't be of more help!

Answer (score 1):

Lets start my trying to solve the simplest possible variant of the problem: Lets assume N people and K timeslots, but only one possible announcement. Lets also assume that each person will only ever stay for one timeslot and that each person who hasn't yet shown up has an equally probable chance of showing up at any future timeslot.

Given these simplifications, at each timeslot you look at the payoff of announcing at the current timeslot and compare to the chance of a future timeslot having a higher payoff, eg, lets assume 4 people 3 timeslots:

Timeslot 1: Person 1 shows up, so you know you could get a payoff of 1 by announcing, but then you have 3 people to show up in 2 remaining timeslots, so at least one of those timeslots is guaranteed to have 2 people, so don't announce..

So at each timeslot, you can calculate the chance that a later timeslot will have a higher payoff than the current by treating the remaining (N) people and (K) timeslots as being N independent random numbers each from 1..k, and calculate the chance of at least one value k being hit more than or equal to the current-payoff times. (Similar to the Birthday problem, but for more than 1 collision) and then you need to decide hwo much to discount based on expected variances. (bird in the hand, etc)

Generalization of this solution to the original problem is left as an exercise for the reader.